# How non root user able to run on privilige port

Tags: linux, docker

I supposed to get bind exception instead it binding the port

```
% docker run --rm -u nobody  alpine  nc -l 0.0.0.0 443
```

```
% docker exec -it b2b471d05398 sh
~ $ id
uid=65534(nobody) gid=65534(nobody)
~ $ ps
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 nobody    0:00 nc -l 0.0.0.0 443
    8 nobody    0:00 sh
   15 nobody    0:00 ps
~ $ %
```

Tried this one too, still it is able to bind port less than 1024

```
 docker run --rm -u nobody --cap-drop=SETUID --cap-drop=NET_BIND_SERVICE --cap-drop=SETFCAP --cap-drop=NET_RAW  alpine  nc -l 0.0.0.0 443
```

Answer (score 0):

This is by design. See the documentation at
[Privileged ports are not mapped within containers](https://docs.datadoghq.com/security_platform/default_rules/cis-docker-1.2.0-5.7/).

> The TCP/IP port numbers below 1024are considered privileged ports. Normal users and processes are not allowed to use them for various security reasons. Docker does, however allow a container port to be mapped to a privileged port.
> [...]
> Docker does, however, allow a container port to be mapped to a privileged port on the host if the user explicitly declares it. This is because containers are executed with NET_BIND_SERVICE Linux kernel capability which does not restrict privileged port mapping. The privileged ports receive and transmit various pieces of data which are security sensitive and allowing containers to use them is not in line with good security practice.

Docker executes with Linux kernel capability that allows the binding.
So the binding works for Docker, even if it conflicts with normal usage.